# Acknowledge SO in a peer reviewed publication?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Do people consider it appropriate/ polite to acknowledge SO and its users in the Acknowledgements section of a peer reviewed publication?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking about the appropriateness on the Academia site. Would it be polite? Certainly!

Comment: Is the Acknowledgements section the same as References/Citations? If so, then yes.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Usually, Acknowledgements is for sponsors of the research or for coworkers or helpers not listed among the authors. It's optional who you place there, like with acknowledgments in the preface to a book. Unless Stack Exchange as a company directly aided you in your work, I'd think you wouldn't need to reference them there.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks. That goes to show you how many peer reviewed papers I read. rbatt, if you've gotten help from a post on Stack Overflow, it should probably be cited in your references.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37706/stack-overflow-as-a-reference-in-a-professional-paper-presentation